# REST в контексте сложного ресурса

Tags: rest

В работе появилась ситуация, не очень хорошо укладывающаяся в традиционный REST: есть сущность (денежная транзакция), которая после создания может быть обновлена только однократно (корректно завершена или отменена). Т.е. обработка сущности происходит следующим образом:

```
transaction [id=<uuid> state=pending] 

(волшебное обновляющее действие путем воздействия на API через HTTP)

transaction [id=<uuid> state=completed] или transaction [id=<uuid> state=cancelled]
```

Безусловно, я могу объявить PUT-контроллер, который будет ловить пейлоад формата `{"state": "completed"}` и применять его к транзакции, если она еще не была завершена тем или иным способом. Однако подобный подход кажется мне откровенно костыльным, мне кажется, что PUT-запросы в общепринятом понимании REST не должны блокироваться такими сложными правилами валидации. Есть ли более красивое решение внутри общепринятого видения REST?

Comment: Чем не угодили `POST transaction/{uuid}/complete` и `POST transaction/{uuid}/cancel` ?

Comment: @Nofate тем, что на самом деле ресурс не создается. Ну и что реального такого подресурса нет, и ресурс сам по себе подразумевает сущность и должен выражаться существительным.

Comment: Как по мне, это адвокатство правил. Можно представить себе это как создание трансформации для стэйт-машины, которая переведет ресурс `transaction/{uuid}` в то или иное состояние. Причем трансформация-таки может быть вполне реальным ресурсом и выполняться асинхронно. Если придираться к существительным, то это могут быть POST `transaction/{uuid}/completion` и `POST transaction/{uuid}/cancellation`

Comment: GitHub API для изменения состояния Issue, например, использует предложенный вами подход, только не с `PUT`, а с `PATCH`.

Comment: @Nofate да есть такое. Я просто пытаюсь все от начала и до конца сделать по канону хотя бы на уровне интерфейса. Тут на самом деле вообще просится нечто другое вместо REST, но я не могу его в одном месте выкинуть.

Comment: Вот тут [длинная статья](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) про Good Practices и кроме моего варианта и вашего тоже ничего нет.

Comment: @Nofate пока сделаю через подресурсы (completion, cancellation), вопрос на всякий оставлю открытым